# How to reverse an ArrayList without the reverse method?

Tags: java, methods, arraylist, reverse

Hello I am trying to reverse an ArrayList without the reverse method. I just wanted to make it work without the method. I can't seem to get it right. 
This is what i have so far:

```
for (int x = nums.size()-1; x>=0; x--)
    {

        for(int z =0; z<nums.size();z++)
        {
            nums.set(z, x);

        }
    }
```

This is my output:
run:
0
1
2
3

1
1
1
1
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 0 seconds)

Comment: you are doing it twice and rearranging it back to the way it was

Comment: @VirtualBaseClass - Actually, he's not.  If he was, the output would be "0 1 2 3" not "1 1 1 1".

Comment: @StephenC yeah.. another problem is that he is setting the value x, not getting it from the array. Dunno why its 1111 though, shouldn't it be the last value that x takes which is 0.

Comment: @VirtualBaseClass - *"Dunno why its 1111 though"*.  I suggest that you get a pencil and paper and "hand execute" the code.  Then you'll understand.

Comment: @StephenC Don't really need a pen and paper for it, thanks for the remark though. And I still think its 0000. Would be grateful if you point out what I am missing.

Comment: @VirtualBaseClass - Actually, if you are missing something you DO need a pencil and paper.  Seriously.  Just try it.

Comment: @StephenC Tried.. still getting 0 0 0 0.. ran it in code.. still same answer.. i am not seeing something that u are.. would you please point it out.. thank u for ur patience

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/38701/discussion-between-virtualbaseclass-and-stephen-c)

Answer (score 1):

You can ascend from the bottom & simultaneously descend from the top (`size() - 1`) swapping elements, and stop when you meet in the middle.

```
int i = 0;
int j = nums.size()-1;
while (i < j) {
    int temp = nums.get(i);
    nums.set( i, nums.get(j));
    nums.set( j, temp);
    i++; j--;
}
```

Comment: Do you mind putting it in a for loop? i wanna understand it better.

Comment: @JB - You should attempt to understand it in its current form.  It is easier to understand this way than as a `for` loop.

Comment: Since there are *two* loop indexes you need two declarations, two initializations and two advancements. Putting the syntax in a "for" loop can be done (except perhaps for the declarations), but it would reduce clarity.

Answer (score 0):

You can swap in pairs at a time, coming in from both ends toward the center:

```
for (int i = 0; i < nums.size()/2; i++) {
    Integer left = nums.get(i);
    Integer right = nums.get(nums.size()-1-i);
    nums.set(i, right);
    nums.set(nums.size()-1-i, left);
}
```

By using `Integer` instead of `int` for `left` and `right`, Java doesn't have to keep converting between `int` and `Integer` values (the first being a primitive, the second being an actual object).  This improves performance.

Comment: You don't know if autoboxing is happening here

Comment: `ArrayList` can only store objects, so in this case `Integer` instances would be stored and not `int`.  When you read the documentation at http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#get%28int%29 you will notice that the return type is given as `E`, which in this case refers to `Integer`.  If this answer said `int left = nums.get(i)`, then the `Integer` returned would be converted to `int` and then stored in `left`.  Then it would be converted into `Integer` in `nums.set(...` again.